# Dynamically setting resources of a Java web app

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, web, glassfish

Specifically, I'm talking about a GlassFish server and a MySQL database.

I am creating the JDBC data source for my application via `asadmin` on deployment. Since I want to be able to run multiple instances of my application at the same time, I want the data source (and also authentication realm) identifiers to be variable and configurable using Docker environment variables.

Basically, I want each application instance to have its own database, but at the same time I want all instances to share the same application and MySQL server.

So I need to be able configure entries in the `persistence.xml` and `web.xml` at deploy time (specifically the `jta-data-source` of my persistence unit and `realm-name` of my login config).

This sounds like an easy enough task but turns out to be incredibly difficult. There are a few solutions that I found but are very hacky in my opinion:

- Modify the deployment descriptors using Maven and build a different `.war` per instance. Obviously I don't want to build a new application per instance if they all share the same code.
- Modify the deployment descriptors after deployment in the GlassFish domain file system. This would require a server restart and two deployments for each instance.
- Make all instances share the same database. Is this a common practice? Seems like unnecessary overhead.
- Use system properties and `${reference}` them in the descriptors. I simply cannot find a proper way to set application-scoped system properties using GlassFish.

So how would I go about this?

On another note: when modifying the authentication realm at runtime, I always need to restart the server, correct? Is there any way around it? Are there any better ways to approach this general use case (answer is probably yes)?

Comment: Not exacly your scenario but alot of tweaks which can be useful. I made a example docker file for deploying wildfly apps with runtime and build configuration. Look here: https://github.com/BITFORCE-IT/WildFlyApp

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a way that's not too ugly for my taste. It is kind of similar to what @rene-m does in his WildFly Dockerfile and also to what I have already been doing to my SQL database setup scripts.

1. I have replaced the strings for the data source and authentication realm with placeholders:

   ```
   <jta-data-source>_SOURCE_NAME_</jta-data-source>
   <realm-name>_AUTH_REALM_</realm-name>
   ```
2. In the deployment script I extract `web.xml` and `persistence.xml` and replace the placeholders with the deployment parameters. In an Alpine shell script this looks like this:

   ```
   # Update .war deployment descriptors.
   $JAVA_HOME/bin/jar -xfv $WAR_FILE WEB-INF/web.xml
   $JAVA_HOME/bin/jar -xfv $WAR_FILE WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml
   sed -i "s|_AUTH_REALM_|$AUTH_REALM|g" WEB-INF/web.xml
   sed -i "s|_SOURCE_NAME_|$SOURCE_NAME|g" WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml
   $JAVA_HOME/bin/jar -ufv $WAR_FILE WEB-INF/web.xml
   $JAVA_HOME/bin/jar -ufv $WAR_FILE WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml
   rm -rf WEB-INF/
   ```

This works quite well and I'm only modifying the container-scoped `.war` file which is confined to a single deployment instance anyway. It shifts the procedure of the first approach posted in the OP (Maven) from compile to deploy time.

Answer (score 0):

With GlassFish, it is possible to override the `web.xml` and `glassfish-web.xml` descriptor at deploy time. In `asadmin` deploy command, you can specify path to them with `--altdd` and `--runtimealtdd` respectively.

And when using resource references, you don't need to modify persistence.xml at all! You just need to map your JTA datasource to another JNDI name in `glassfish-web.xml`:

```
<resource-ref>
  <res-ref-name>_SOURCE_NAME_</res-ref-name>
  <jndi-name>jdbc/AlternativeJTADataSource</jndi-name>
</resource-ref>
```

You could then do the following when deploying:

- unpack `web.xml` from the WAR (the web.xml should already define the `resource-ref`)
- replace the default realm name with whatever you need
- create a `glassfish-web.xml` with mapping for the JTA resource ref
- deploy with something like: `asadmin deploy --altdd web.xml --runtimealtdd glassfish-web.xml application.war`